# WeatherLink File (WLK) to CSV with Python

Tags: python

I really need your help because I'm trying to solve this for some time now but cannot get it done!

We have a Davis Weather Station with the WeatherLink Software. This is downloading all weatherdata from the station and saving it to a yyyy-mm.wlk File.

I would like to visualize it within PowerBI but the wlk Files seem to be saved in a binary encoded kind.

So I started programming with python to convert it anyhow to a csv file. I eaven found a Java based solution here: [Java Program WLK Reader](https://github.com/jeryini/wlk-reader)
I tried to use this code and make it running in python but nothing worked. Does anyone have an idea how I can convert these files?

So far I tried this:

```
#from PyByteBuffer import ByteBuffer #https://pypi.org/project/PyByteBuffer/
import struct

in_file = open(r"D:\Temp\WeatherStation\2013-08.wlk", "rb")
data = in_file.read()
in_file.close()

#content = data.decode('ansi').splitlines()
content = data.decode('ansi', 'slashescape')

#offset = 0
#content = struct.unpack_from("<L", data, offset)

with open(r"D:\Temp\WeatherStation\Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for line in content:
        text_file.write(line)

#decoded = data.decode('ansi', 'slashescape')

#offset = 0
#content = struct.unpack_from("<d", data, offset)
#data.decode('ansi', 'slashescape')
```

I'm comletely lost with this and have no idea what I can do to get this done and hope that maybe someone of you can help me...

As soon as I get it done I'll post the code here so everybody can use it within PowerBI to visulize it more nicely than within WeatherLink :-)

You can find example files right here: [Example Files](https://github.com/jeryini/wlk-reader/tree/master/test/test)

Thank you very much!

Victor

Here comes the detailed File Description from the Readme as Ronald mentioned:

> Data File Structure
>
> What follows is a technical description of the .WLK weather database
>   files. This is of interest mostly to programmers who want to write
>   their own programs to read the data files.
>
> The data filename has the following format: YYYY-MM.wlk where YYYY is
>   the four digit year and MM is the two digit month of the data
>   contained in the file.
>
> The structures defined below assume that no bytes are added to the
>   structures to make the fields are on the "correct" address boundaries.
>   With the Microsoft C++ compiler, you can use the directive "#pragma
>   pack (1)" to enforce this and use "#pragma pack ()" to return the
>   compiler to its default behavior.
>
> //   Data is stored in monthly files.  Each file has the following
>   header. struct DayIndex  {    short recordsInDay;  // includes any
>   daily summary records    long startPos;    // The index (starting at
>   0) of the first daily summary record };
>
> // Header for each monthly file. // The first 16 bytes are used to
>   identify a weather database file and to identify //   different file
>   formats. (Used for converting older database files.) class HeaderBlock
>   {     char idCode [16]; // = {'W', 'D', 'A', 'T', '5', '.', '0', 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0}    long totalRecords;    DayIndex dayIndex [32];
>   // index records for each day. Index 0 is not used
>                              // (i.e. the 1'st is at index 1, not index 0) };
>
> // After the Header are a series of 88 byte data records with one of
>   the following //   formats.  Note that each day will begin with 2
>   daily summary records
>
> // Daily Summary Record 1 struct DailySummary1 {    BYTE dataType = 2;
>   BYTE reserved;    // this will cause the rest of the fields to start
>   on an even address
>
> short dataSpan;   // total # of minutes accounted for by physical
>   records for this day    short hiOutTemp, lowOutTemp; // tenths of a
>   degree F    short hiInTemp, lowInTemp;   // tenths of a degree F
>   short avgOutTemp, avgInTemp; // tenths of a degree F (integrated over
>   the day)    short hiChill, lowChill;     // tenths of a degree F
>   short hiDew, lowDew;         // tenths of a degree F    short
>   avgChill, avgDew;      // tenths of a degree F     short hiOutHum,
>   lowOutHum;   // tenths of a percent    short hiInHum, lowInHum;     //
>   tenths of a percent    short avgOutHum;             // tenths of a
>   percent    short hiBar, lowBar;         // thousandths of an inch Hg
>   short avgBar;                // thousandths of an inch Hg    short
>   hiSpeed, avgSpeed;     // tenths of an MPH    short dailyWindRunTotal;
>   // 1/10'th of an mile     short hi10MinSpeed;          // the highest
>   average wind speed record     BYTE  dirHiSpeed, hi10MinDir; //
>   direction code (0-15, 255)    short dailyRainTotal;        //
>   1/1000'th of an inch    short hiRainRate;            // 1/100'th
>   inch/hr ???    short dailyUVDose;           // 1/10'th of a standard
>   MED    BYTE  hiUV;                  // tenth of a UV Index    BYTE
>   timeValues[27];         // space for 18 time values (see below) };
>
> // Daily Summary Record 2 struct DailySummary2 {    BYTE dataType = 3;
>   BYTE  reserved;   // this will cause the rest of the fields to start
>   on an even address
>
> // this field is not used now.    unsigned short todaysWeather; //
>   bitmapped weather conditions (Fog, T-Storm, hurricane, etc)
>
> short numWindPackets;      // # of valid packets containing wind
>   data, 
>                                 // this is used to indicate reception quality    short hiSolar;             // Watts per meter squared
>   short dailySolarEnergy;    // 1/10'th Ly    short minSunlight;
>   // number of accumulated minutes where the avg solar rad > 150
>   short dailyETTotal;        // 1/1000'th of an inch    short hiHeat,
>   lowHeat;     // tenths of a degree F    short avgHeat;             //
>   tenths of a degree F    short hiTHSW, lowTHSW;     // tenths of a
>   degree F    short hiTHW, lowTHW;       // tenths of a degree F
>
> short integratedHeatDD65;  // integrated Heating Degree Days (65F
>   threshold)
>                                 // tenths of a degree F - Day
>
> // Wet bulb values are not calculated    short hiWetBulb,
>   lowWetBulb; // tenths of a degree F    short avgWetBulb;          //
>   tenths of a degree F
>
> BYTE dirBins[24];          // space for 16 direction bins 
>                                 // (Used to calculate monthly dominant Dir)
>
> BYTE timeValues[15];       // space for 10 time values (see below)
>
> short integratedCoolDD65;  // integrated Cooling Degree Days (65F
>   threshold)
>                                 // tenths of a degree F - Day    BYTE  reserved2[11]; };
>
> // standard archive record struct WeatherDataRecord {    BYTE dataType
>   = 1;    BYTE archiveInterval;      // number of minutes in the archive    // see below for more details about these next two fields)    BYTE
>   iconFlags;            // Icon associated with this record, plus Edit
>   flags    BYTE moreFlags;            // Tx Id, etc.
>
> short packedTime;          // minutes past midnight of the end of
>   the archive period    short outsideTemp;         // tenths of a degree
>   F    short hiOutsideTemp;       // tenths of a degree F    short
>   lowOutsideTemp;      // tenths of a degree F    short insideTemp;
>   // tenths of a degree F    short barometer;           // thousandths
>   of an inch Hg    short outsideHum;          // tenths of a percent
>   short insideHum;           // tenths of a percent    unsigned short
>   rain;       // number of clicks + rain collector type code    short
>   hiRainRate;          // clicks per hour    short windSpeed;
>   // tenths of an MPH    short hiWindSpeed;         // tenths of an MPH 
>   BYTE windDirection;        // direction code (0-15, 255)    BYTE
>   hiWindDirection;      // direction code (0-15, 255)    short
>   numWindSamples;      // number of valid ISS packets containing wind
>   data
>                                 // this is a good indication of reception     short solarRad, hisolarRad;// Watts per meter squared
>   BYTE  UV, hiUV;            // tenth of a UV Index
>
> BYTE leafTemp[4];          // (whole degrees F) + 90
>
> short extraRad;            // used to calculate extra heating
>   effects of the sun in THSW index
>          short newSensors[6];       // reserved for future use    BYTE  forecast;            // forecast code during the archive interval
>
> BYTE  ET;                  // in thousandths of an inch
>          BYTE soilTemp[6];          // (whole degrees F) + 90    BYTE soilMoisture[6];      // centibars of dryness    BYTE leafWetness[4]; 
>   // Leaf Wetness code (0-15, 255)    BYTE extraTemp[7];         //
>   (whole degrees F) + 90    BYTE extraHum[7];          // whole percent
>   };
>
> Notes:
>
> Always check the dataType field to make sure you are reading the
>   correct record type
>
> There are extra fields that are not used by the current software. For
>   example, there is space for 7 extra temperatures and Hums, but current
>   Vantage stations only log data for 3 extra temps and 2 extra hums.
>
> Extra/Soil/Leaf temperatures are in whole degrees with a 90 degree
>   offset. A database value of 0 = -90 F, 100 = 10 F, etc.
>
> The rain collector type is encoded in the most significant nibble of
>   the rain field.  rainCollectorType = (rainCode & 0xF000); rainClicks =
>   (rainCode & 0x0FFF);
>
> Type      rainCollectorType 
>   0.1 inch  0x0000
>   0.01 inch 0x1000
>   0.2 mm        0x2000
>   1.0 mm        0x3000
>   0.1 mm        0x6000 (not fully supported)
>
> Use the rainCollectorType to interpret the hiRainRate field. For
>   example, if you have  a 0.01 in rain collector, a rain rate value of
>   19 = 0.19 in/hr = 4.8 mm/hr, but if you have  a 0.2 mm rain collector,
>   a rain rate value of 19 = 3.8 mm/hr = 0.15 in/hr.
>
> Format for the iconFlags field The lower nibble will hold a value that
>   will represent an Icon to associate with this data record (i.e. snow,
>   rain, sun, lightning, etc.). This field is not used.
>
> Bit (0x10) is set if the user has used the edit record function to
>   change a data value. This allows tracking of edited data.
>
> Bit (0x20) is set if there is a data note associated with the archive
>   record. If there is, it will be found in a text file named
>   YYYYMMDDmmmm.NOTE. YYYY is the four digit year, MM is the two digit
>   month (i.e. Jan = 01), DD is the two digit day, and mmmm is the number
>   of minutes past midnight (i.e. the packedTime field). This file is
>   found in the DATANOTE subdirectory of the station directory.
>
> Format for the moreFlags field The lowest 3 bits contain the
>   transmitter ID that is the source of the wind speed packets recorded
>   in the numWindSamples field. This value is between 0 and 7. If your
>   ISS is on ID 1, zero will be stored in this field.
>
> WindTxID = (moreFlags & 0x07);
>
> Time values and Wind direction values in Daily Summary records These
>   values are between 0 and 1440 and therefore will fit in 1 1/2 bytes,
>   and 2 values fit in 3 bytes. Use this code to extract the i'th time or
>   direction value. See below for the list of i values.
>
> fieldIndex = (i/2) * 3;   // note this is integer division (rounded
>   down)
>
> if (i is even)    value = field[fieldIndex] + (field[fieldIndex+2] &
>   0x0F)<<8;
>
> if (i is odd)        value = field[fieldIndex+1] +
>   (field[fieldIndex+2] & 0xF0)<<4;
>
> A value of 0x0FFF or 0x07FF indicates no data available (i.e. invalid
>   data)
>
> The time value represents the number of minutes after midnight that
>   the specified event took place (actually the time of the archive
>   record).
>
> The wind direction bins represent the number of minutes that that
>   direction was the dominant wind direction for the day.
>
> Index values for Daily Summary Record 1 time values Time of High
>   Outside Temperature   0 Time of Low Outside Temperature    1 Time of
>   High Inside Temperature    2 Time of Low Inside Temperature     3 Time
>   of High Wind Chill            4 Time of Low Wind Chill             5
>   Time of High Dew Point             6 Time of Low Dew Point
>   7 Time of High Outside Humidity      8 Time of Low Outside Humidity
>   9 Time of High Inside Humidity      10 Time of Low Inside Humidity
>   11 Time of High Barometer            12 Time of Low Barometer
>   13 Time of High Wind Speed           14 Time of High Average Wind
>   Speed   15 Time of High Rain Rate            16 Time of High UV
>   17
>
> Index values for Daily Summary Record 2 time values  Time of High
>   Solar Rad             0 Time of High Outside Heat Index    1 Time of
>   Low Outside Heat Index     2 Time of High Outside THSW Index    3 Time
>   of Low Outside THSW Index     4 Time of High Outside THW Index     5
>   Time of Low Outside THW Index      6 Time of High Outside Wet Bulb
>   Temp 7 Time of Low Outside Wet Bulb Temp  8 (Time value 9 is not used)
>
> Index values for Dominant Wind direction bins in Daily Summary Record
>   2 N    0 NNE  1 NE   2 ... NW  14 NNW 15

Comment: Ok, nice challenge. I would write my own python read_wlk module. BUT, for this you really need to know the internal file format of the binary file. As I do not have this weather station, the only thing I could find was this: "Full technical details of the file format are in the readme file which is usually access from the Windows Start button in the Weatherlink section."

Comment: Have you checked out: https://github.com/beamerblvd/weatherlink-python ?

Comment: Wow! Amazing! I will have a look into this :-) I hope it'll do what I want because I want to use the already created files from WeatherLink... But I'll let you know what I find out...

Comment: Hi! I'm also interested in this topic, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Hi @SaverioGuzzo, This is what I did so far: https://github.com/SAR71/WLK_FileConverter Didn't have the time to continue but feel free to use the code :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to export the data as a .txt file over the WeatherLink GUI and then use a common Python library such as pandas to read a .txt file.
In my version 6.0.3 I go to the data table page (yellowish paper and pen symbol (1.)). Then under Reports (2.) is an export option.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see in github that somebody wrote a package in Python:

https://github.com/beamerblvd/weatherlink-python

Install it by: pip install git+https://github.com/beamerblvd/weatherlink-python

this person didn't provide any documentation unfortunately.
So using the tests you have to figure it out.

The tests folder's content will help you to figure out how to use it.